# What is conformal symmetry physically?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

I'm reading a paper by t'Hooft http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6675.
There is an argument in the paper that I could not understand: "Now that system, described by Maxwell’s equations, does have conformal symmetry, generated by the transformations $x_μ → λx_μ/x^2$, with arbitrary con- stant λ, to be added to the other generators of the Poincar ́e group. What this means is that, if we only use light rays and nothing else, to measure things, then absolute sizes and time spans cannot be observed, only relative ones." So, my question is how if we only use the light rays, then only relative sizes and spans can be realized? I understand if we have no rulers or clocks then we can not talk about (space or time ) distances. But with only ligth rays how one can talk about relative distances from physical and mathematical point of view?

Comment: Suppose a light ray travels from A to B. Just as it arrives, another ray leaves B, headed toward A. At the same time, suppose the same thing happens for A and C, but with two round trips. If the initial rays leave together and the final rays arrive together, then the distance AB is twice AC.